# How to interact a page with another page?

Tags: angular

The user is on the page **cash-account-statements**, I will want to have two hyperlinks.

One hyperlink for  **FACTURE NUMERO 000012354**

And the second for **FACTURE NUMERO 000012368**

[first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iJYF.png)

```
cash-account-statements.component.html
```

```html
 <table id="customers">
      <tr>
        <th>Date of operation</th>
        <th>Value date</th>
        <th>Name of the operation</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10/10/2020</td>
        <td>11/11/2020</td>
        <td>You previous balance</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11/10/2020</td>
        <td>12/11/2020</td>
        <td>FACTURE NUMERO 000012354</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12/10/2020</td>
        <td>13/11/2020</td>
        <td>FACTURE NUMERO 000012368</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

When the user clicks on **FACTURE NUMERO 000012354** for example, he is directed to the page **annexes**.

How to interact `cash-account-statements.component.html` to `annexes.component.html`?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p8vqmp?file=src/app/views/portfolio/cash-account-statements.component.html)

Comment: How exactly do you want to interact with each other? What data do you want to pass from one component to another? be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must setup routing in your Angular app. If you create your app with:

```
ng new angular-app --routing=true
```

then you will have a file called app-routing.module.ts

In that file declare your top level lazy loaded routes. Then for each lazy loaded route create a routing module with:

```
ng generate module module-name --routing=true
```

Now you will be able to declare your child routes.

The top level lazy loaded routes look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    loadChildren: () => import('./routes/main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule)
  },
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/main'}
]
```

And the routing for the children for each module looks something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'cash-account', component: CashAccountStatementsComponent},
  {path: 'annexes/:id', component: AnnexesComponent}
]
```

Here, to access cash-account page go to http://localhost:4200/main/cash-account

To access a specific account go to http://localhost:4200/main/annexes/000012354

To switch between urls use something like:

```
<a routerLink="/main/annexes/000012354">0000012354</a>
```

To access the value of :id in your annexes component use:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  the.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    console.log(params.id)
    // typically you will make an HTTP call here using the ID to populate the component
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you do not route via the components itself. You use something that is called an [Angular Router](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5).

There should be an RoutingModule in which the different routes are defined. For example `/annexes` should route to your `AnnexesComponent`. Then you provide the url you want the user to route to instead of the component.

I advice you to read the documentation use [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tkn9xq?file=src/app/views/portfolio/annexes.component.html) (where I edited the example you provided) to wrap your head arround this concept.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tkn9xq?file=src/app/views/portfolio/annexes.component.html